# Gearman returns result before completing all tasks

Tags: php, symfony, gearman

I´m using gearman for parallel processes and improve the performance of an application developed in Symfony2.

Parallel processing works correctly, but, few days ago I discovered that when I have a group of works being performed and the first gearman ends, it backs me a result of this work and others still running in the background.

This is a problem for me, because I need all the answers of the jobs run in parallel if I want that my application works correctly.

I need to implement a series of works synchronously and in parallel.

Here is my configuration gearman bundle:

```
gearman:
    # Lista de bundles donde Gearman va a buscar Workers
    bundles:
        # Aquí declaramos cada uno de los bundles donde se van declarar workers de Gearman
        # Nosotros vamos a usar el MainBundle, donde tenemos definidos nuestros workers
        MainBundle:

            # Nombre del bundle ()
            name: AppBundle

            # Bundle search can be enabled or disabled
            active: true

            # Lista de directorios donde gearman va a buscar las definiciones de workers
            # == MUY IMPORTANTE == -> estos directorios deben de existir dentro del bundle, sinó Gearman dará un error
            include:
                - Services
                - Workers

            # Directorios que se van a ignorar
            ignore:
                - DependencyInjection
                - Resources

    # Valores por defecto que va a usar Gearman en la definición de los workers
    # Estos valores se pueden especificar para cada worker
    defaults:

        # Default method related with all jobs
        # do // deprecated as of pecl/gearman 1.0.0. Use doNormal
        # doNormal
        # doBackground
        # doHigh
        # doHighBackground
        # doLow
        # doLowBackground
        method: doNormal

        # Default number of executions before job dies.
        # If annotations defined, will be overwritten
        # If empty, 0 is defined by default
        iterations: 0

        # Default amount of time in seconds required for the execution to run.
        # This is useful if using a tool such as supervisor which may expect a command to run for a
        # minimum period of time to be considered successful and avoid fatal termination.
        # If empty, no minimum time is required
        # minimum_execution_time: null

        # Default maximum amount of time in seconds for a worker to remain idle before terminating.
        # If empty, the worker will never timeout
        # timeout: null

        # execute callbacks after operations using Kernel events
        callbacks: true

        # Prefix in all jobs
        # If empty name will not be modified
        # Useful for rename jobs in different environments
        job_prefix: null

        # Autogenerate unique key in jobs/tasks if not set
        # This key is unique given a Job name and a payload serialized
        generate_unique_key: true

        # Prepend namespace when callableName is built
        # By default this variable is set as true
        workers_name_prepend_namespace: true

    # Server list where workers and clients will connect to
    # Each server must contain host and port
    # If annotations defined, will be full overwritten
    #
    # If servers empty, simple localhost server is defined by default
    # If port empty, 4730 is defined by default
    servers:
        localhost:
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 4730
```

If you need more information, please request them.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide what the PHP code looks like that is queuing up the jobs?